# How to eradicate duplicate items while adding in Existing WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, listview

In my WPF window, I have a list view (lvw1) of 3 columns. While adding a new list view item, I want to check if item doesn't exist already. I'm using the following line of code

```
if (!lvw1.Items.Containskey(keyitem))
```

**Keyitem** is the string cross-checked with existing items. I guess **Containskey** method doesn't work in wpf.

Please suggest alternative/appropriate code.

Comment: My ListView is added items in following way. 
`lvw1.Items.Add(new { Col1 = txt1.Text, Col2 = txt2.Text, Col3 = txt3.Text });`
Now I want to check if new List view item to be added doesn't exist already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Contains()` method, just assign the new object you would create to a variable and check if it exists already in the `ListView`:

```
var newObject = new { Col1 = txt1.Text, Col2 = txt2.Text, Col3 = txt3.Text };
if(!lvw1.Items.Contains(newObject)){
    lvw1.Items.Add(newObject);
}
```

**Update** to make it ignore the case:
Probably the easiest way to do that is to create a `class` for your type and override `Equals`.
This works because `ItemCollection`'s (the type of `Items`) `Contains` method uses the `Equals` method internally to check equality of the containing objects.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
    public string Text3 { get; set; }

    public Item(string text1, string text2, string text3)
    {
        this.Text1 = text1;
        this.Text2 = text2;
        this.Text3 = text3;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var compareObject = obj as Item;
        if (compareObject == null) return false;
        return Text1.ToLower().Equals(compareObject.Text1.ToLower()) &&
            Text2.ToLower().Equals(compareObject.Text2.ToLower()) &&
            Text3.ToLower().Equals(compareObject.Text3.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Then, instead of creating an `anonymous object`, create an instance of this type.

```
var newObject = new Item(txt1.Text, txt2.Text, txt3.Text); //use new Item() here
if(!lvw1.Items.Contains(newObject)){
    lvw1.Items.Add(newObject);
}
```

Comment: How could we avail Ignore case functionality while adding new Listviewitem?   Plz suggest @Domysee

Comment: @Shalem I have updated the answer to suit your needs

Comment: Thanks for code. 
I Just used ToUpper() method and it worked :                                             

**`var newObject = new { Col1 = txt1.Text.ToUpper(), Col2 = txt2.Text.ToUpper(), Col3 = txt3.Text.ToUpper() };`**

Comment: My requirement is to get Ignore case functionality. So casing doesn't count here

Answer (score 0):

You can find the item by text:

```
ListViewItem item = lvw1.FindItemWithText("item text");
if (item == null)
{
    // does not exist. add to list
}
```

Comment: How are you adding the items?

Comment: I have text boxes. I'm adding text provided in them to ListView in following manner:   

`lvw1.Items.Add(new { Col1 = txt1.Text, Col2 = txt2.Text, Col3 = txt3.Text });`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ItemCollection.IndexOf Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589122.aspx)  like this:

```
if (lvw1.Items.IndexOf(keyitem) < 0)
{
    // add the object
}
```

Note this will implicitely use the keyitem object's Equals method, whatever that does. If it's not ok, then you'll have to enumerate the whole collection (using Linq methods for example) for something that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System.Linq;

...
object o = new { Col1 = txt1.Text, Col2 = txt2.Text, Col3 = txt3.Text });
if (!lvw1.Items.Cast<dynamic>().Any(d => IsEqual(d, o))) {
    // add item
}
...

private static bool IsEqual(dynamic a, dynamic b) {
    return a.Col1 == b.Col1 && a.Col2 == b.Col2 && a.Col3 == b.Col3;
}
```